# Error trying to delete a dynamic allocated matrix using the destructor

Tags: c++

As the title says i try to delete a dynamic allocated matrix using the destructor and i get the following error:

> Exception thrown at 0x78D8DB1B (ucrtbased.dll) in oop.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDCD.

Here is the code that i try to run.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

     template<class T>
    class Matrice
    {
    private:
        int marime;
        T** matrice;
    public:
        Matrice(int marime);
        ~Matrice();
        friend istream& operator>>(istream& in,Matrice<T>& mat) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mat.marime; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mat.marime; j++) {
                    cout << "Matrice[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
                    in >> mat.matrice[i][j];
                }
            }
            return in;
        }
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,Matrice<T> mat) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mat.marime; i++) {
                cout << endl;
                for (int j = 0; j < mat.marime; j++) {
                    out << mat.matrice[i][j]<<" ";
                }
            }
            return out;
        }
    };

    template<class T>
    Matrice<T>::Matrice(int marime) {
        this->marime = marime;
        matrice = new T * [marime];
        for (int i = 0; i < marime; i++) {
            matrice[i] = new T[marime];
        }
    }
    template<class T>
    Matrice<T>::~Matrice() {
        for (int i = 0; i < marime; i++) {
            delete[] matrice[i]; //Here is where i get the error.
        }
        delete[] matrice;
    }

int main()
{
    Matrice<int> test(3);
    cin >> test;
    cout << test;
}
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.  Fix those warnings.  Add `Matrice(Matrice const&) = delete;`

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`? If not allowed, write your own (simplified) version of it.

Comment: `DDDDDDCD` likely means the memory was already freed.

Answer (score 1):

The memory address `0xddddddcd` is a likely sign of a use-after-free bug, since Visual C++ debug builds tag all freed memory with that memory pattern. I compiled your program using ASAN on Linux (`clang++ matrice.cc -g -Og -fsanitize=address`) and was able to replicate your issue with the following stacktrace:

```
==6670==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x603000000010 at pc 0x0000004c9a76 bp 0x7fffdcd001b0 sp 0x7fffdcd001a8
READ of size 8 at 0x603000000010 thread T0
    #0 0x4c9a75 in Matrice<int>::~Matrice() /tmp/z.cc:44:22
    #1 0x4c93c9 in main /tmp/z.cc:54:1
    #2 0x7f34a76370b2 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:308:16
    #3 0x41f3cd in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x41f3cd)

0x603000000010 is located 0 bytes inside of 24-byte region [0x603000000010,0x603000000028)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x4c736d in operator delete[](void*) (/tmp/a.out+0x4c736d)
    #1 0x4c93c1 in main /tmp/z.cc:53:5
    #2 0x7f34a76370b2 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:308:16

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x4c6b1d in operator new[](unsigned long) (/tmp/a.out+0x4c6b1d)
    #1 0x4c9536 in Matrice<int>::Matrice(int) /tmp/z.cc:36:19
```

It looks like some resource is read by the destructor at line 44 col 22 (`delete[] matrice[i];`) after it has already been freed by a destructor called from line 53 (`cout << test`).

The reason for this is easy to miss at first. The destructor was being called twice, once after `cout << test` and again at the end of `main`.

The issue is as follows: the function `friend istream& Matrice::operator>>` takes a parameter of type `Matrice<T>&`, which is fine, while `operator<<` takes just a `Matrice<T>` by value. This causes your instance of `test` to be copied, by the [default copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor). This is a problem, because the default copy constructor doesn't deep-copy your arrays, but it just copies the pointers themselves.

When the private copy of `test` used in `operator<<` is destructed, it frees the same arrays that were used by `test`; thus when the destructor of `test` runs, it tries to read that already-freed array.

This hits the notion of the [rule of 5/3/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three): if your class requires a custom destructor, a custom copy constructor, or a custom `operator=`, it almost certainly needs all three. The cleanest way to resolve this would be a copy constructor that deep-copies the contents of the matrix to a new set of arrays. You could alternatively delete the copy constructor (`Matrice(Matrice<T> const&) = delete`), but this makes your class a little less flexible to use.

Comment: wow, thank you for the indepth explanation about the reason of why this error occurs.